# Can the F1 score be equal to zero?

Tags: classification, performance, metric, confusion-matrix, f1score

As it is mentioned in the [F1 score Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score), *'F1 score reaches its best value at 1 (perfect precision and recall) and **worst at 0**'*.

What is the worst condition that was mentioned?

[image]

Even if we consider the case of: ***either precision or recall is 0***.
The whole ***F1-score*** value becomes undefined. Because when either ***precision*** or ***recall*** is to be 0, ***true postives*** should be 0. When the ***true positives*** value becomes 0, both the ***precision*** and ***recall*** become 0.

Comment: also posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/459549/232706

Answer (score 7):

F1 will never be zero, but very near to zero for a bad classifier. If TP or TN is zero then there isn't any need to check F1.

Answer (score 5):

It's a mistake on Wikipedia.

$F_{1}$ as the **harmonic mean** is defined only at **positive** real numbers. $PRE$ or $REC$ could be equal 0 in case $TP=0$. Which provides to undefined result $F_1=\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: Have you added something to the talk page for that Wikipedia article (to point out mistake)?

Answer (score 2):

**It can't be exactly zero**. We need exactly one (only one) of precision. Or recall to be zero to make f1 = zero, but both have "tp" as the numerator.

```
#### Will be Nan
y_test = np.array([0,0,1,1])
y_pred = np.array([0,1,0,0])

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred).ravel()
precision = tp/(tp+tn)
recall = tp/(tp+fn)
f1 = 2*precision*recall/(precision+recall)
print(f1)
```

> nan

```
#### Can be ~0 with a specific case, with this data
y_test = np.hstack((np.zeros((1,2)),np.ones((1,1000000))))
y_pred = np.hstack((np.ones((1,1)),np.zeros((1,1000000)),np.ones((1,1))))
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test[0], y_pred[0]).ravel()
precision = tp/(tp+tn)
recall = tp/(tp+fn)
f1 = 2*precision*recall/(precision+recall)
print('{0:1.6f}'.format(f1))
```

> 0.000002

Answer (score 1):

If we go by the formula, it can actually be zero when when at least one of precision or recall is zero (regardless of the other one being zero or undefined). Look at the formulas for precision, recall, and F1:

[image]

[image]

[image]

By looking at the F1 formula, F1 can be zero when TP is zero (causing Prec and Rec to be either 0 or undefined) and FP + FN > 0. Since both FP and FN are non-negative, this means that F1 can be zero in three scenarios:

1- TP = FP = 0 ^ FN > 0,

2- TP = FN = 0 ^ FP > 0,

3- TP = 0 ^ FP > 0 ^ FN > 0.

In the first scenario, Prec is undefined and Rec is zero. In the second scenario, Prec is zero and Rec is undefined, and in the last scenario, both Prec and Rec are zero.

Comment: Ooh, +1.  "Harmonic mean of precision and recall" is problematic when either is zero, but by expanding precision and recall to their confusion-matrix components, we fill in the removable discontinuity.  Note that for this expanded version of F1 to be undefined, we need $TP=FN=0$, but that implies that there are no positive examples in the dataset, quite a degenerate problem.

Comment: @BenReiniger: Thanks for your comment. I updated my answer. TP = FN = 0 does not necessarily mean that F1 is undefined; FP should also be zero; otherwise, F1 would be zero.

Comment: yes, I was only stating the one directional implication.

Comment: Oh, yeah, in that case, you're absolutely correct.